# Rails nested form error: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an app that allows a user to create a contest. Each contest has many questions and each contests has many entries. Each entry has many answers and each question has many answers. Here are my models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :question
end

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :questions
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contest
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :contest
end
```

Everything works except for when I try to create an entry. I get a "param is missing or the value is empty: entry" error. Here is my controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_contest

  # GET /entries
  # GET /entries.json
  def index
    @entries = Entry.all
  end

  # GET /entries/1
  # GET /entries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /entries/new
  def new
    @entry = Entry.new
  end

  # GET /entries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /entries
  # POST /entries.json
  def create
    @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
    @entry.contest = @contest
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.save
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /entries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /entries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @entry.update(entry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @entry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /entries/1
  # DELETE /entries/1.json
  def destroy
    @entry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_entry
      @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_contest
      @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:contest_id, answers_attributes: [:id,  :content, :entry_id, :question_id, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

And here is my entry form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@contest, @entry]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <h3>Questions</h3>
    <%= simple_fields_for :answers do |ff| %>
        <% @contest.questions.each do |question| %>
            <h4><%= question.content %></h4>
            <%= ff.input :content, input_html: {class: 'form-control'} %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am still working on the logic but am perplexed as to why the entry form is giving me this error. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE

In the Rails Guide example they show the new action as:

```
def new
  @person = Person.new
  2.times { @person.addresses.build}
end
```

Do I need to build the answer objects in my new action? I'm not sure... I tried it but it didn't work. I feel like that can't be the problem though as the error is coming from the `entry_params` method

Comment: Where are you getting the error? The rails console should give you a line number, from which you should be able to tell us where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Jon the error is coming from line 77 in the entry controller which is the params require line in the entry params method. I tried the solution by Pavan below but it did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding this line to your **`new`** action.

```
@entry.answers.build
```

And change this line

```
<%= simple_fields_for :answers do |ff| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :answers do |ff| %>
```

Comment: I just tried moving the set_contest method above the private keyword and still had the same error. Any other suggestions?